# Elasticsearch: Prevent two instances from accidentally running

Tags: elasticsearch

Does anybody know how to prevent two instances of Elasticsearch 2.4.0 from accidentally starting on a single node while maintaining PID file integrity.  I can prevent two from starting if I uncomment node.max_local_storage_nodes; however, the PID file that is generated using the "-p" command line argument still gets generated when the "second" instance starts, and then gets deleted when it fails.  This prevents the "first" instance from stopping using a simple kill command and I have to find it by seeing which Java instance is running said application.

Any help would be appreciated.